# Converting a csv file to json in Gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, json, csv, gatsby

I am using GatsbyJs and I am looking at using the`gatsby-transformer-csv` plugin, documentation [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-csv/). I have two csv's from WordPress that I have exported that I want to use with Gatsby. I am fine with just getting one to work and figuring out the other after. For the two csv files there are corresponding ID's that match, since some of the content IE; title and content is in one csv and Images are in the other csv. I have installed the transformer plugin, but I am not sure where to put my csv file and how to convert it to json, and then once converted to Json how to go about outputting it as a react component on a specific page.

All I see is a how to query section, which doesn't mean much to me but looks like this

```
  allLettersCsv {
    edges {
      node {
        letter
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will generaly want to use this plugin together with `gatsby-source-filesystem` plugin.

The `gatsby-source-filesystem` reads in your **.csv** files then `gatsby-transformer-csv` **transforms** the .csv content into data you can query with graphQL.

So if you put your **.csv** files in `./src/data`, your gatsby config should look like this:

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [ 
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `data`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data/`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-csv`,
  ],
}
```

Then you can use your graphQL query to get your data into your component's props.

You can see an example project at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-csv